# Ошибка в структуре php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку в коде? Движок отказывается его воспринимать (Opencart).

```html
<?php if ($route=='' || $route=='common/home' ) { ?>
<div class="newsletter">
  <?php } else { ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="newsletter newsletter-catalog">
  <?php } ?>
  <?php else if ($route=='category/product' ) { ?>
  <div class="newsletter newsletter-catalog1">
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Вообще включай вывод ошибок, или заглядывал в лог

Answer (score 5):

Блок `else` должен быть последним.

Answer (score 2):

Если разобрать вашу конструкцию, то получается штука такого вида:

```
if ($route=='' || $route=='common/home' ) {
    <div class="newsletter"> }
else {
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="newsletter newsletter-catalog">
     }
else if ($route=='category/product' ) {
     <div class="newsletter newsletter-catalog1">
}
```

В свою очередь, если обратиться к документации [PHP:else if](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php), то сразу становится понятно, что у вас не верно построена структура, а именно должно быть так:

```
if -> else if -> else
```

Следовательно нужно немного изменить код и привести к такому виду:

```
 <?php if ($route=='' || $route=='common/home' ) { ?>
          <div class="newsletter">
 <?php } else if ($route=='category/product' ) { ?>
     <div class="newsletter newsletter-catalog1">
 <?php } else { ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsletter newsletter-catalog">
    <?php } ?>
```